# login_required next not redirecting

Tags: django, django-2.0, login-required

I'm working through a tut in the book Django 2 By Example with PyCharm and Chrome. I'm using Django 2.0.8 as specified in the book. As it says, I have the following base.html template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <span class="logo">Bookmarks</span>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <ul class="menu">
        <li {% if section == "dashboard" %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
          <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">My dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li {% if section == "images" %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
          <a href="#">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li {% if section == "people" %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
          <a href="#">People</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="user">
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        Hello {{ request.user.first_name }},
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log-in</a>
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This seems to log me in some of the time? It will work once, then I log out and it won't let me log in again.

My views.py has a login_required view that redirects to a dashboard template and assigns a section context:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

My settings.py assigns login urls like this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'

LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

If I log into the admin page then go to my login page it shows the dashboard properly like this:

[image: Screenshot of dev]

But I can't log in from the login screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@login_required` use `@login_required(login_url="/this_is_your_url/ok/")`

Comment: Am I not specifying that in the settings? Also I don't want to hard code the url?

Comment: DO you import this `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
`

Comment: Yeah that's what I've got in my imports